# Expectation-Maximization with dependent latent variables

Tags: maximum-likelihood, inference, expectation-maximization, variational-bayes

Deriving the equations for a Expectation Maximization over my model, I end up with a posterior for the latent variables (E-step) that prevents me from going on.

**Generative model**

I assume my data is generated as follows:

1. Assign a cluster  $z$ to every point $x_i$: $z_i \sim Categorical(\pi)$
2. Create N combinations of points (observed). $c_n$ indicates how many points of every cluster are in combination $n$. We need to estimate $\mathbf{z}$ in order to compute $\mathbf{c}$
3. Assign a score to every combination, $y_n \sim \mathcal{N}(c^Tw, \sigma)$

Thus:
\begin{equation}
y_n \sim \mathcal{N}(c^Tw, \sigma)\\
z_i \sim Categorical(\pi) 
\end{equation}

**Goal**: I want to find the $\mathbf{w}$ and infer the $\mathbf{z}$.

When I arrive to the **E-step** I get:
\begin{equation}
Q_n(\mathbf{z}) = 
\frac{
p(y_n, \mathbf{z} | \mathbf{w})
}
{
\sum_{\mathbf{z}} p(y_n, \mathbf{z} | \mathbf{w})
}
=
\frac{
p(y_n | \mathbf{z} , \mathbf{w}) p(\mathbf{z} | \pi)
}
{
\sum_{\mathbf{z}} p(y_n | \mathbf{z},  \mathbf{w}) p(\mathbf{z} | \pi)
}
=
\frac{
p(y_n | \mathbf{z_{(n)}} , \mathbf{w}) p(\mathbf{z_{(n)}} | \pi)
}
{
\sum_{\mathbf{z}} p(y_n | \mathbf{z_{(n)}},  \mathbf{w}) \mathbf{z_{(n)}} | \pi)
}
= 
p(\mathbf{z_{(n)}} | y_n, \mathbf{w})
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{z_{(n)}}$ is the assignment $z$ of the set of points in the combination $n$.

**Issue**: The number of points is arond 100.000, therefore computing the sum in the denominator is not an option. Besides, I can't factorize it since the output $y_n$ depends not on one point but on all the latent variables $\mathbf{z_{(n)}}$ associated to the points in that combination $n$.

**Question:** Is this a suitable problem for Variational Inference (or any other method) or this dependence can be overcome in EM?

**EDIT** (Use case)

Imagine that there are three professions in the world $a,b,c$ (astronauts, doctors and statisticians) and that we want to model the Gross Domestic Product of a city as a linear regression of its inhabitants professions.

E.g:

- City A: GDP of 10.000. 10% austronauts, 30% doctors, 60% statisticians.
- City B: GDP of 5.000. 30% austronauts, 30% doctors, 40% statisticians.
- ...

People can work in many cities at the same time -otherwise the problem would have many solutions and I couldn't infer anything-, therefore being considered as inhabitants in many cities.

The GDP for city $i$ would be:

\begin{equation}
y^{(n)} = w_0 + w_1 c_a^{(n)} + w_2 c_b^{(n)} + w_3 c_c^{(n)} + \epsilon
\end{equation}

The goal is to find the latent professions ($\mathbf{z}$) and the contribution of every profession to the GDP ($\mathbf{w}$)

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer the question.

Comment: @TomMinka I elaborated it a bit more, I hope this makes it more comprehensible.

Comment: You only observe a single $y_n$?  That doesn't seem like enough information to make useful inferences.  What parameters are you trying to estimate in the M-step?

Comment: I observe the scores $y$ (for thousands of cases) and the points $x$ of every case, that contributed to that score in a linear regression fashion. In the M-step I would estimate the coefficients $w$ and the mixing proportions $\pi$.

Comment: But then why is $\mathbf{z}$ conditioned on a single $y_n$?  Is $\mathbf{z}$ supposed to be indexed by $n$?

Comment: $y_n$ depends on: $w$ and $z$ of points (or individuals) in the $n$−th city. $z_i$ depends on the $y_n$ of every city $i$ works in. So you're right, we can reduce to $z_n$, meaning the set of $z$ of those who work in that city.

Comment: Maybe I should have said it earlier, but I am (very) interested on the $\mathbf{z}$.